# Double reported speech?

Tags: grammaticality

Is there such thing as a double reported speech?

> I **told** her that you **told** me that you won't come to class tomorrow.

Here, I want to report to a friend that I reported her words to someone else, but I'm not sure if this "double reporting" is possible and how I would phrase the sentence above.

Comment: There's no "grammatical" restriction on how deeply you can nest such constructions. For example, I could tell my father that you told her that someone told you that they won't come to class tomorrow. And although it might tax my father's language processing skills a bit, he could presumably report all that back to me... You get the drift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a valid sentence and represents this sequence of actions:

1. You told me you won't come to class.
2. I told her what you said.
3. I am telling you now about event #2.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of reported speech. And you're right, it's reporting reported speech! The important thing here is to focus on the tense shifts. In your sentence, I would actually prefer:

"I told her that you told me that you **wouldn't** come to class tomorrow."

When we report the verb "will" (either positive or negative), we shift to "would." This is important, because since you're working with a complicated construction, clarity is really important.